# Set.map now returns a Set warning scala

Tags: scala

I am getting this warning on mapping on sets, but I want to maintain the set output. How do we go about fixing this? I do not want to suppress the warning.

> warning: method map in trait SetLike has changed semantics in version 2.8.0:
> Set.map now returns a Set, so it will discard duplicate values. 
> someSet.map(_.fullName)

signature

`def mapSet(someSet: Set[People]): Set[String]`

Comment: **Scala** `2.8.0`? Holy cow, that was already ancient 6-7 years ago when I started to learn the language. - Anyways, the warning is especially telling you that `Set.map` will return a `Set` so you are okay.

Answer (score 1):

Using Scala v2.7 REPL:

```
scala> scala.collection.mutable.Set("a","aa","b").map{x => x.size}
res0: Iterable[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 1, 2)
```

Using Scala v2.8 REPL:

```
scala> scala.collection.mutable.Set("a","aa","b").map{x => x.size}
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2)
```

This difference between Scala 2.7 and 2.8 mutable `Set` (precisely speaking `SetLike`) can change program semantics, so the migration warning is shown.